# PHP8.1-Redis Module For Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: package-management, updates, php

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 server and I am trying to upgrade php7.4 to php8.1.

I am encountering the fllowing error:

```
# php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'redis.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/redis.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/redis.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20210902/redis.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/redis.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 8.1.8 (cli) (built: Jul 11 2022 08:29:57) (NTS)
```

therefore I attempt to install the php8.1-redis package, but encounter this error:

```
# apt-get -y install php8.1-redis
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php8.1-redis
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.1-redis'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php8.1-redis'
```

Therefore I ran `apt policy php8.1` and I did not see php8.1-redis.

**Question:**
Is php8.1-redis simply not available for ubuntu 20.04 server or do I need a different repo?

I am currently using these php repos:

```
focal/main  http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/apache2/ubuntu
focal/main  http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/apache2/ubuntu
focal/main/restricted   Yes http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
focal-updates/main/restricted  http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
focal/universe  http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
focal-updates/universe  http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
focal/multiverse  http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

looking for definitive answer so that I can pressure webhosting company to upgrade ubuntu version (if necessary).

Answer (score 1):

Ran across this as well. Someone in here should've replied to this sooner. I want to post the solution so others will find the answer quicker. The repos don't have php8.1-redis obviously as you found out. You have to install it directly.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y autoconf

wget https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/refs/heads/develop.zip
unzip develop.zip
cd phpredis-develop
phpize
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

go to php.ini and update this

```
 extension=redis.so
```

check it

```
php -m | grep redis
```

Comment: thanks for the reply... I solved the problem a while back... but to be "Captain Obvious" here. A package that is a core component of a major app like Nextcloud... should be added to the repos... and this question should have been wholly unnecessary..

Answer (score 0):

Redis is more complex to install than "user-land" PHP packages but may yield better performance for applications that heavily use Redis.

I tried for a few hours to config this extension on my Ubuntu 22.04 with PHP8.1 after installing `redis-server`.

Following the extension's official document is a bit complicated. Hope this command will help you.

```
sudo apt install php8.1-redis
```

Source: https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/22.04/ubuntu-universe-arm64/php8.1-redis_5.3.5+4.3.0-5.1_arm64.deb.html